# Where did the option for converting MySQL to PL/SQL using Oracle Devloper's Scratch Pad go?

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I found [this](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/products/migration/scratchlauncher-098387.html) video where you could use Oracle Developer's Scratch Pad to convert MySQL scripts to PL/SQL scripts. However, when I installed the latest version this conversion option doesn't show up in Scratch Pad.

Here's what the video showed:

[image: MySQL to PL/SQL in video]

Any idea what version is being used in the video? Or how to enable it in the latest version? Any suggestions of other ways to do the conversion without selling my soul?

Answer (score 0):

I'm using version 3.2.20.29 (but it was present also in [version 2.1](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/what-is-sqldev-093866.html)). I found the Translation Scratch Editor here:

[image]

Comment: It is there, but the question was about Scratch Editor allowing to convert from MySQL to PL/SQL, a feature which is shown on the video, but it is not accessible in any of the SQLDeveloper versions. I checked the 2.1 version and this option is not available. I found this: [No MySQL to PL/SQL conversion in SQLDeveloper](https://forums.oracle.com/thread/879793) where one person states that this feature is not available, even though it is shown on the video.

Comment: you are right, even on the SQL Developer documentation the conversion from MySQL is just a set of guidelines for a manual conversion http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E35137_01/doc.32/e18461/triggers_proc_mysql.htm#g1049668

Comment: Indeed. I can find the editor, it's just that I cannot find the MySQL to PL/SQL option. Thank you for your answer anyway.